# Improve vuejs performance

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm quite new to vuejs and have some performance issues with my project.

When displaying some components it takes a "long" time to display them on the depending on the size of the list.

I have 2 nested v-for that display the data, the outer v-for creates component 1, and then component 1 creates more components 2 (see beautiful image made in paint).

The number of components 1 are between 0 and 15, while the components 2 are between 0 and 200

My application it's structured like the image

[Structure image](https://forum.vuejs.org/uploads/default/original/2X/8/85fda9014fc6c140921f2e5865b1d2fcf10195ee.png)

The problem is that with a list of 7 components 1 and 70 components 2 it takes 300ms to display, which I would like to improve since I think it's quite slow.

In the image you can see the screenshot taken from the Chrome performance tool (the screenshot was taken in development mode but also in production the situation is slightly better, like 20ms faster).

What are my options to improve performance?

[Performance image](https://forum.vuejs.org/uploads/default/original/2X/d/d6e61f74747dd4380b4096a7cb429bc45b9cb94e.png)

After playing a little bit I've noticed that the "problem" is the Component 2. More precisely a huge part of the 300ms are used only for the  (there are 7 router-link in each component 2). By removing them I get about 150ms, which is already a huge improvement.

Why does it take so much to render the router-link?

Comment: i would suggest to use infinite scroll or pagination technique for loading less componenets to combat this scenario. Donot load everything at once

Comment: That's an option and it works, using https://peachscript.github.io/vue-infinite-loading/#!/ I'm able to cut down the loading time to 130ms. But I would like to improve it in other ways as well. The fact that each router-link takes 20ms to "load" is way too much.